# Magento UPS shipping methods displaying “Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time”

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout

my store view is multi store view for US.

I have configured UPS in Magento 1 store.

[image]

I am having this problem at checkout, it keeps displaying "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." for all products.

Here is my test Billing address place at checkout

[image]

```
I have checked the error log, there is no log for shipping.
```

Comment: i think i have read a post aimilar to this and his solution was changing the protocol of a gateway from `http` to `https`